# If I draw 4 cards from a standard deck of 52, what is the probability the cards add to 20?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, gambling

Assume the cards have the following values:

K, Q, J, = 10

Ace-10 = 1-10

The long way to do this would be to calculate ways the cards can add up to 20 and divide by $50C4$ and do this for every possible way. For example:

Assume I draw a 2 of hearts, Jack of Spades, 5 of clubs and a 3 of diamonds.

That's one possible combination, $\left(\frac{4C4}{52C4}\right)$ 
You'd then have to find all the other possible combinations and add them together.

To find all the possible combinations this way would be too exhausting and time consuming, so I was wondering if there was another way to approach this question

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through all the possible four-card hands with a computer program (I used the Python itertools module) shows that the number of hands which sum to 20 is $10,225$.  So the probability that the cards will sum to 20 is
$$\frac{10,225}{\binom{52}{4}}=0.0377690$$